# Looking to update cells format to percent in gspread, receiving keyError

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm looking to update a column of cells to percentages, so conditional formatting can apply to them. When I run the following:

```
requests = [{
    "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 3,
            "endRowIndex": 27,
            "startColumnIndex": 2,
            "endColumnIndex": 3
        },
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
                "numberFormat": {
                    "type": "PERCENT",
                    "pattern": "####.#"
                }
            }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
    }
}]

res = wks.batch_update(requests)
print(res)
```

I'm given the error:

```
KeyError: 'range'
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? Appreciate the help.

Comment: From your error of `The full error message is: "dict(vr, range=absolute_range_name(self.title, vr["range"])) for vr in data TypeError: string indices must be integers"`, unfortunately, I think that this error is not related to your showing script. So in this case, I think that my proposed modification will be able to be used after your current issue was resolved. So in the current stage, unfortunately, my answer was not useful for your current issue. By this, I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I would like to recommend updating your question by showing your script for correctly replicating your current issue.

Comment: Your solution did fix my code. I have changed wks.batch_update({"requests": requests}) to sh.batch_update({"requests": tree}) as sh is my designated sheet as opposed to wks, which is the entire document. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `wks.batch_update(requests)`, wks should be the result of `sa.open`, not the specific worksheet (as it was here)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following code for your use case it will fix your requirements.

in your code, you are missing parameter placement.

```
requests = {
    "requests": [
        {
      "repeatCell": {
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
                "numberFormat": {
                    "type": "PERCENT",
                    "pattern": "0.00%"
                }
            }
        },
        "range": {
          "sheetId": w23._properties['sheetId'],
          "startRowIndex": 3,
          "endRowIndex": 27,
          "startColumnIndex": 2,
          "endColumnIndex": 3,
        },
        "fields":  "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
      }
    }
    ]
}

response=sh.batch_update(body=requests)
```